# why parent component never render until child router is complete?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In my vue application I have route inside route. the problem is until the inner route is resolved then the outer/parent route is display.

Here is how I defined the routes:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  // Use the HTML5 History API (fallback to URL hash if unsupported)
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "base",
      component: Base,
      children: [{ path: "", name: "home", component: Home }]
    }
  ]
});
```

The problem is vue is waiting for `beforeRouteEnter` to complete then it show the `Home` and `Base`.

If I remove the `next()` from `beforeRouterEnter` in the `Home` the component base is never display.

This is a problem because Home can take a lot of time to load data meanwhile base should be render to screen (base has toolbar for example).

[Here is example of the problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-typescript-sandbox-9e5bn)

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Vue renders from bottom to top. That means your inner most component will render before it traverses up the tree. Why is it taking so long to load Home?

Comment: not just home, any page, get the data may take a while. I want if the component is ready then just render.. vue doesn't support this way?

Comment: It's not the support that's really the issue. You're not resolving (i.e. invoking `next()`) until your data is resolved – the component never gets created until the route is resolved therefore no child components or routes will resolve until your parent does.

Comment: and what if the data taking for 20 seconds? I have to see blank page until the data is resolve?

Comment: Well, yes, because that's what you're telling it to do. If Base is so vital, don't block Base in Home's route guard. You're essentially simulating SSR. Instead, do `hardWork` on created, [for example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-typescript-sandbox-wt9w5), and show some progress.

Comment: This is the expected behavior. If you don't want to block the parent from displaying, don't block the child in `beforeRouteEnter`. You can resolve the route and then perform the data fetching inside the child component without blocking the router.

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes you need to fetch data from the server when a route is
>   activated. We can achieve this in two different ways:
>
> 1. Fetching After Navigation: perform the navigation first, and fetch
>      data in the incoming component's lifecycle hook. Display a loading
>      state while data is being fetched.
> 2. Fetching Before Navigation: Fetch data before navigation in the
>      route enter guard, and perform the navigation after data has been
>      fetched.

Since your fetch takes too much time, your preferable approach would be the first aforementioned. Jest perform your API calls in `mounted`/`created` hooks of `Home.vue` component.